# Dot Product Can't Auto-Parallelize and Auto-Vectorize at the same time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing, vectorization

I want to test the speed of compiler optimization when the compiler both parallelizes and vectorizes my code for the scalar dot product, but for some reason the compiler is only allowing me to either vectorize my code or parallelize is but not both.

Below is my code which I currently I am not able to get to parallelize (it is giving me the error code of 1004)

```
float dot_product(float* a, float* b, int N) {
    float result = 0;
    #pragma loop(hint_parallel(0))
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            result += (*(a+i) * *(b+i));
    }
    return result;
}
```